# VueJs data binding issue

Tags: vue.js

I try to bind attributes and some data to my template but the code below doesn't work. What I need is to render n-amount of templates depends of amount of printedForms objects and implement in each template data from proper object. 
Please give any ideas what wrong with my code.

P.S. I've warning in console as follows:
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "printedForm.docNumber": TypeError: Cannot read property 'docNumber' of undefined (found in component: )

```
 <div id="app">
  <printing-form v-for="printedForm in printedForms" track-by="id"></printing-form>
 </div>

 <template id="printingForm-template">
   <img v-bind="printedForm.attributes">
   <div>{{ printedForm.docNumber }}</div>
 </template>
```

My VueJs code below:

```
Vue.component('printing-form', {
  template: '#printingForm-template'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    printedForms: [
      {
        id: 1,
        docNumber: 7,
        attributes: {
          src: '/waybill/img/4p_bus.png',
          width: 1400,
          height: 980
        }
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        docNumber: 7777,
        attributes: {
          src: '/waybill/img/4p_cargo.png',
          width: 1400,
          height: 980
        }
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        docNumber: 10000,
        attributes: {
          src: '/waybill/img/4p_selfMove.png',
          width: 1400,
          height: 980
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to bind a `printedForm` property `:printed-form="printedForm"` like that

```
<printing-form v-for="printedForm in printedForms" 
track-by="id" :printed-form="printedForm"></printing-form>
```

and define it in component props

```
Vue.component('printing-form', {
  template: '#printingForm-template',
  props: ['printedForm']
});
```

[Vue props](http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props)

Notice when using camelCased prop names as attributes, you need to use their kebab-case (hyphen-delimited) equivalents

[Vue Docs](http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case)

Comment: Beat me to it so I won't post my answer. Another thing I'd mention though it's not really related to the question is the component's template should have one root element.

Comment: no it shouldn't , it depend on what you are doing, i made that example check it [vue exmple](https://jsbin.com/radezoq/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Yes it should. In Vue 2 it's required. In Vue 1 you will end up with fragment instances and performance costs. http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance

Comment: @BillCriswell you are right , i found that in the Migration from Vue 1.x